# HashSet vs Cursor vs Any other solution for AdBlocker

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, hashset

I'm just developing an **AdBlocker** for an **Android browser**. Now I'm faced with the question, which would be the fastest method.

The hosts file has **10,000+ entries**. When loading a website, a lot of elements are searching for a match, so there might be a lot of requests.

Which method would you recommend to get the best performance?

My idea: I could use a **Cursor** and a **SQLite database** for this. This is what I'm using for the history, bookmarks, etc.

Other idea: A **HashSet** stored in the **SharedPreferences**.

As I know, a **Cursor** is very fast for single requests within a huge list, but for each request a new cursor is created, so it could be not optimal if a lot of requests are made.

A **HashSet** can be stored in RAM, but I don't know much about its performance for huge lists.

So what about the runtimes of each method? Or do you know a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: https://github.com/nhachicha/SnappyDB, note [this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/0f6193a1f84aa8a77d07ac18d3566b87bc89999b/687474703a2f2f736e6170707964622e636f6d2f696d672f62656e63686d61726b5f73716c6974655f776974685f7472616e73616374696f6e2e706e67) performance numbers

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good database lib. But what is with a HashSet in this case?

Comment: HashSet its not persistent :-(

Comment: and you can use snappydb for hosts, bookmarks, history etc, so you can get rid of sqlite for good

Comment: Ok I will try it. What do you think about Realm? In some cases it seems to be a good database too.

Comment: realm? Its a weapon for different animals, you now trying to catch flies, not elephants... ;-)

Comment: but seriously, i never tried realm, so i cannot tell if it is really that better than good, old sqlite...

Comment: Thanks. I will try to make a benchmark later between the different solutions.

Comment: good luck then... post the results here, could be interesting